# How to customize .inputrc to make Command-Delete and Option-Delete delete lines and words in iTerm 2?

Tags: macos, keyboard, iterm

I'd like to add a little bit of consistency between editing text in the terminal and editing text in normal OS X programs. I use iTerm2, but I imagine any solution would involve using readline and `.inputrc` which probably would work in most terminals.

Specifically, I was thinking of adding:

- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd>: Delete to start of line before cursor
- <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd>: Delete word before cursor
- <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd>: Move cursor between words
- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd>: Move cursor to start/end of line

### Questions

- How could `.inputrc` be configured to support these keyboard shortcuts?
- Would any of these shortcuts generate conflicts with existing terminal or command-line shortcuts?
- Are there any other shortcuts that would be useful to create consistency with standard OS X text editing keys?

As a side note, I am aware that there are Vi and Emacs style shortcuts for performing these operations. In fact I use [Vi-style shortcuts quite a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6241492/180892) on the command-line. However, sometimes when my mind hasn't shifted modes, it’s disruptive. Thus, it would be nice if the terminal could support both OS X and Vim style shortcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

⌘← can be assigned to `\eOH` and ⌘→ to `\eOF`. You could assign ⌥← to `\eb` like in Terminal, but it doesn't work in vi mode or nano.

[image]
[image]

In emacs mode you could also add this to .inputrc:

```
"\e[1;9D": backward-word
"\e[1;9C": forward-word
"\e[3~": kill-word
```

`C-v` shows the escape sequence for the next key combination. `^[` is ESC in caret notation. `bind -p` prints currently bound commands.

Answer (score 1):

*Preliminary answer; still hunting for other key combinations*

The following post explains [how to configure Alt+left/right](http://brettterpstra.com/option-arrow-navigation-in-iterm2/) in Iterm2. Interestingly, it requires both the configuration of `.inputrc` and customisation of iTerm2.